# Add Key in Dictionary dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

Below is the code where `key` is being hard-coded in `Dictionary`

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
      { "ID",     Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]) },
      { "STATUS", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Name"]) },
      { "TYPE",   Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TYPE"]) }
  };

  datalist.Add(data);
}
```

Now, instead of hard-coding the keys like `ID`, `STATUS`, etc, I want to add it from my string array containing the values below

```
string[] arrNames = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameKey"].Split(',');
```

How can I traverse `arrNames`to add keys in Dictionary and then add in `List`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Seems you need to use ToList() and ToDictionary() methods:
http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/10/21/c.net-little-wonders-todictionary-and-tolist.aspx

Let me know if I didn't understand you.

Comment: Seems like a nested loop is in your future. A hint: `Dictionary<string, string>` as an `Add(string key, string value)` method.

Comment: It depends on how an element of `arrNames` looks like. You could do `ToDictionary()`

Comment: Your dictionary keys don't match the DataTable columns, how do you know which column corresponds to which dictionary key? Using indexes or....?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Key and Datatable Column will always match as per our business logic

Comment: Suppose you have a string variable called `key`. You could then use `data.Add(key, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][key]));` Does that help? You would put that code in a loop - you wouldn't use a collection initializer like you are now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the collection of names:

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

string[] arrNames = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameKey"].Split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var name in arrNames)
    {
        data[name] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][name]);
    }

    datalist.Add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

your code should look something like this

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
string[] arrNames = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameKey"]).Split(',');

if (arrNames.Length == 3)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
  {
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { arrNames[0], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][arrNames[0]]) },
        { arrNames[1], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][arrNames[1]]) },
        { arrNames[2], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][arrNames[2]]) }
    };

     datalist.Add(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq method `ToDictionary`. Try this code:

```
string[] arrNames = // new[] {"ID", "STATUS", "TYPE"};

var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
    datalist.Add(
        arrNames
            .Select(key =>
                new
                {
                    key,
                    value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][key])
                }
            )
            .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer LINQ-y and concise you could try something like:

```
var names = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameKey"].Split(',');
var list = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => names.ToDictionary(n => n, n => r[n]))
            .ToList();
```

Here I'm assuming `dt` is a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least the same number of items in your `arrNames` array than columns you want to read and of course with this order, then you can hardcore the indexes.

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
      { arrNames[0], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]) },
      { arrNames[1], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Name"]) },
      { arrNames[2], Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TYPE"]) }
  };

  datalist.Add(data);
}
```